# nput stream read does not convert all data

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I am writing application for Android devices, which have to communicate with some other device via bluetooth. (the other device its just a board like Raspery pi with attached bluetooth)

This other device accept list of command which I are single bytes like 'A', 'X', 'C' etc. and when you sending command it always returns some response which is something like 'OK', 'ERROR4' or somethoer data like '0000000000000001230120000000'.

I have implemented most of the command in my application and they work fine. But I have issue with last command which return 1748 bytes. Most of the time I am using this method to getting response, and it works fine:

```java
private String send(byte [] bytes) {
        if(bluetoothService == null)
            return null;

        if(bluetoothSocket == null)
            return null;

        String line = "";

        Log.wtf("BYTESARR", Arrays.toString(bytes));

        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream inputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();

            outputStream.write(bytes);
            outputStream.flush();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            line = r.readLine();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return line;
    }
```

But for that command where response is 1748 bytes method above freezing my app. So I implemented second method only for that command, which you see below.

```java
OutputStream outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream inputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();

            outputStream.write(bytes);
            outputStream.flush();

            char [] b = new char[1540];
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            int from = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < EXCEPTIONS_NUMBER; i++){
                int asdf = r.read(b, from, 50); // from and len are related to B not R
                Log.wtf("READ", asdf + " <");
                from += asdf;
            }

            line = new String(b);

Log.wtf("LINE", line);
```

But problem with that method is my response looks like this: (

```
...0000000000000������������...
```

Less then half of this response are 0 (zeros), which is what I was expecting, but second part of this response are those strange question marks(which I believe should be zeros) and I do not know why is that?

Question 1) Why first method making my app freeze when I am reading response with 1748bytes?
Question 2) Why second method is giving me that strange question marks instead of zeros?

***EDIT [Solved]***
I found the solution. So basically I have to use `ByteArrayInputStream` like this:

```java
byte [] b = new byte[1538];
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
inputStream.read(b);
```

And that allows me read all `bytes` from `b` array and allows me to use `bais` if needed. I am not sure why this solution works, yet. But I am glad it worked. If someone understand it and can explain would be great. If not I will update post, when find out why it is working, if post will be not closed/deleted.

Comment: .readLine() tries to read a line. You may send 1768 bytes but then let the last one be the new line character '\n'.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but It is strange for me that it is working for other commands. Format of response is the same for each command, at least I read it in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. when you call `r.readLine()`, the method will not return until one of two conditions is met: the stream returns a line separator character, or the stream signals it has no more data. If neither of those things happen, your app will "freeze" indefinitely.
2. when you create an array of characters with `new char[1540]`, it's filled with "NUL" characters - a non printing control character with ASCII/Unicode code 0 (don't confuse with "null" object reference in Java). While you read from the stream, you replace some of the content of the array with the characters you read, but some of the original NULs are left in place, and these make it to the string you create later.

To fix, create the string using the portion of the array that you've written to:

```
line = new String(b, 0, from);
```

Comment: Thanks, that help a bit, I mean now I can read a bit more bytes from the device but still the second part of this is that strange "question mark in diamond" sign. Not sure if that mean the device send me an Null (or something like it) but I have told it should be zeros.

Comment: The last line of the answer covers that. It will create the string from the `char`s that you actually received from the device, which is not all the `char`s in the `b` array.

Comment: Before I implemented your solution I was reading 780 zeros and that was a problem right now when I am using your solution I can read around 900 zeros but still 800 "strange question marks" appears in that String. I added to my "for" loop `line = new String(b, 0, from);` but that just help a bit not solved my issue 100%

Comment: Does the device only return digits 0-9 or does it return also text, or perhaps binary data? "�" is also the standard replacement character that is used when binary input cannot be converted to text with the character encoding you're using

Comment: yes, it return letters as well, cause response which I am receiving is <0x0D><COMMAND_BYTE><RES_BYTE><RES_BYTE>......<0x0F> 0x0D - start byte, 0x0F - end byte, command_byte - usually letter, X, Y, T etc. depend on the command, RES_BYTE its is a number cause I am working with date and time only. RES_BYTE is only number, it does not contain colons or slashes.